# verifying success of posting to a user's wall feed using "fb_graph" 1.9.2 on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to tell if posting to a user's wall was successful?  As in:

```
me = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)
me.feed!(
  :message => 'Updating via FbGraph',
)
```

How is the best way to know if it actually made it on their wall?

Answer (score 0):

When you successfully post to a user's feed the return value is the post ID of the newly created post.
See the documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#statuses